# How to conditionally color nodes in a grid with a style

Tags: conditionals, nodes, tikz-styles, grids

I have 3 styles called S1, S2 and S3. I want to conditionally color the nodes.
I tried the \ifnum with no luck. You can see the single line of code
that has been commented out. That is what I conceptually want. This example
is for  3 by 3 grid, but my actual grid is 6 by 6, so it would be great if I could describe the nodes for S1  and S2 using some sort of set notation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[S1/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white!80!black,minimum size=20},
S2/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=red!40,minimum size=20},
S3/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=green!40,minimum size=20}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{(\i - 1) / 3};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{\i - 3 * \y};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x + 3 * (2 - \y)};
%     \node[ IF \label = 4,6,8 THEN S1 ELSE IF \label=1,9 THEN S2 ELSE S3]
 \node[S3]
    (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    \node[above right=0mm of \label]  {\scriptsize\label};
}
\draw (1) -- (2);
\draw (2) -- (3);
\draw (4) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw (7) -- (8);
\draw (8) -- (9);

\draw (1) -- (4);
\draw (2) -- (5);
\draw (3) -- (6);
\draw (4) -- (7);
\draw (5) -- (8);
\draw (6) -- (9);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version adopts `etoolbox`, very powerful package for setting conditions. I guess it could be included in the `\tikzset` but I'm not sure how yet. I'll edit the answer in case.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    filcirc/.style={circle,draw=black,minimum size=20},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{(\i - 1) / 3};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{\i - 3 * \y};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x + 3 * (2 - \y)};
%     \node[ IF \label = 4,6,8 THEN S1 ELSE IF \label=1,9 THEN S2 ELSE S3]
    \expandafter\ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifnumequal{\label}{4}}
        or
        test {\ifnumequal{\label}{6}}
        or
        test {\ifnumequal{\label}{8}}
    }{% then
        \node[filcirc, fill=white!80!black, label={45:\scriptsize\label}] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }{% else
        \expandafter\ifboolexpr{%
            test {\ifnumequal{\label}{1}} or test {\ifnumequal{\label}{9}}
        }{% then
            \node[filcirc, fill=red!40, label={45:\scriptsize\label}] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
        }{% else
            \node[filcirc, fill=green!40, label={45:\scriptsize\label}] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
        }
    }
}
\draw (1) -- (2);
\draw (2) -- (3);
\draw (4) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw (7) -- (8);
\draw (8) -- (9);
\draw (1) -- (4);
\draw (2) -- (5);
\draw (3) -- (6);
\draw (4) -- (7);
\draw (5) -- (8);
\draw (6) -- (9);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) but it is going to be a handful for a 6*6 lattice, isn't it? Unless very few nodes need to be `S1` or `S2`. (Maybe that's the case and the majority are `S3`, as that's evidently the default. Even if I keep thinking `S1` should be intuitively....)

Comment: @cfr thanks. As is, it's very tedious. If I could find a way for it to be automatic it'd be great. I'll look into it later. :D

Comment: See below ? Mine doesn't use **etoolbox**, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it with PGF keys and a couple of macros. It allows you to say

```
\tikzset{%
  S1 set={3,5,8},
  S2 set={1,4},
}
```

for example, to determine which nodes should take each of styles `S1` and `S2`. It is probably a bad idea to name nodes using numbers alone, but I've not changed this in the code below. (Giving each a standard prefix is an easy way to avoid this i.e. `n\variable` rather than `\variable`.)

I've used `\resultx`, `\resulty` and `\resultlabel` to avoid clashes. We then need a temporary variable to hold our result which will be `1`, `2` or `3` depending on the style the node should get.

```
    \let\resultS\relax
```

We now use two loops, each testing if `\resultlabel` is included in one of the defined sets which get styles `S1` or `S2`.

```
    \foreach \j in \Sone
    {
      \ifnum\resultlabel=\j \gdef\resultS{1}\fi
    };
    \foreach \j in \Stwo
    {
      \ifnum\resultlabel=\j \gdef\resultS{2}\fi
    };
```

If not, then we want `S3` instead.

```
    \ifx\resultS\relax\def\resultS{3}\fi
```

Then we use `resultS` in the options for the `\node`

```
    \node[S\resultS] ...
```

[image: conditional styling]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  S base/.style={circle, draw=black, minimum size=20},
  S1/.style={S base, fill=white!80!black},
  S2/.style={S base, fill=red!40},
  S3/.style={S base, fill=green!40},
  S1 set/.store in=\Sone,
  S2 set/.store in=\Stwo,
  S1 set={4,6,8},
  S2 set={1,9},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
  {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\resulty}{(\i - 1) / 3};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\resultx}{\i - 3 * \resulty};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\resultlabel}{\resultx + 3 * (2 - \resulty)};
    %     \node[ IF \label = 4,6,8 THEN S1 ELSE IF \label=1,9 THEN S2 ELSE S3]
    \let\resultS\relax
    \foreach \j in \Sone
    {
      \ifnum\resultlabel=\j \gdef\resultS{1}\fi
    };
    \foreach \j in \Stwo
    {
      \ifnum\resultlabel=\j \gdef\resultS{2}\fi
    };
    \ifx\resultS\relax\def\resultS{3}\fi
    \node[S\resultS] (\resultlabel) at (1.5*\resultx,1.5*\resulty) {\resultlabel};
    \node[above right=0mm of \resultlabel]  {\scriptsize\resultlabel};
  }
  \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,1/4,2/3,2/5,3/6,4/5,4/7,5/6,5/8,6/9,7/8,8/9}
  \draw (\i) -- (\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You might want to look at the `matrix` and/or `chains` libraries for easier ways of drawing your lattice structure. But that is not the subject of this question ....

Comment: (+1) :-). Nice solution without conditionals.  As you see from my answer, I still stick with old `ifthen` ... and `\ifnum` ...

Comment: @Zarko I'm using `\ifnum` ... None of this newfangled `ifthen` stuff ;).

Comment: @cfr Can you explain why you `\let\resultS\relax` and eventually `\ifx\resultS\relax` instead of setting the default initially? This would be useful for people with programming background, but lacking LaTeX expertise.

Comment: @hans_meine No reason, probably. I'd expect either to work. I probably just didn't think about it and did this out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly said, I do not understand what you doing in your code and what should be your result, so the main purposes of this answer is clarify this.

The MWE below generate this picture:

[image]

where colors are select on basis even/odd number in `\label`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, scopes}

\usepackage{ifthen}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style={node distance=0pt,font=\scriptsize},
base/.style = {circle, draw=black, minimum size=20},
S1/.style={base,fill=white!80!black},
S2/.style={base,fill=red!40},
S3/.style={base,fill=green!40}
                    ]
%\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{(\i - 1) / 3};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{\i - 3 * \y};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x + 3 * (2 - \y)};
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\label}}
    {\node[S1,label=above right:\label] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }{
     \node[S3,label=above right:\label] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }
\ifnum\label=1
    \node[S2,label=above right:\label] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};  \fi
\ifnum\label=9
    \node[S2,label=above right:\label] (\label) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};  \fi
}
%     \node[ IF \label = 4,6,8 THEN S1 ELSE IF \label=1,9 THEN S2 ELSE S3]
\scoped[on background layer]
    \draw   (1) -- (3)  (4) -- (6)  (7) -- (9)
            (1) -- (7)  (2) -- (8)  (3) -- (9);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Selecting `\label` as name of nodes content is not good idea, the name is already used in TikZ. As you can see, I slightly simplified your code (why you need two loops with the same variable?), however, for further help you need to tell, what is expected result. Is this grid 6 x 6 circles with different colors? that is the content of circles and what purposes has labels (!), i e. numbers above right of them? At least you see an example, how to use conditions.

**Addendum:**
After (many time) observing of the obtained picture from above code I got a flash, that except the first node (with number 1) nodes in diagonals have equal color which alternate from diagonal to diagonal. For this case I (try to) generalize code for arbitrary numbers of nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, scopes}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{ifthen}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style={inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize},
base/.style = {circle, draw=black, minimum size=20},
S1/.style={base,fill=white!80!black},
S2/.style={base,fill=green!40},
S3/.style={base,fill=red!40},
                    ]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmax}{6}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,\xmax}
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,\xmax}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\x + (\y-1)*\xmax};
    \pgfmathparse{\x+\y}
\ifnum\i=1 
    \node[S3,label=45:\x\y] (\i) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\i}; 
\else
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pgfmathresult}}
        { \node[S1,label=45:\x\y] (\i) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\i};
        }{\node[S2,label=45:\x\y] (\i) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\i};
        }
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This code gives:

[image]

Missing lines between nodes is easy to add. I will make them, when receive confirmation, that my idea lead to desired result of coloring. And for condition I use combination of `\ifnum` and `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: Using `\x` and `\y` isn't the best either? Or does TikZ not actually use these and I've just seen it used by convention?

Comment: I think the question is in that one line of commented code i.e. how to make it do this if-then-else-if-then-else-then thing. But I might be mistaken ....

Comment: I read questions again and after while I got flash: OP actually like to have diagonal nodes except the firs one, which should be red, in the same but alternating color. For this I have new solution, I will upload it soon.

Comment: I think the list is arbitrary. That is, I don't think it is implementing any particular pattern. That's why the OP wants to be able to use set notation i.e. define the sets extensionally rather than intensionally. (Have I got that the right way around?) But maybe I'm wrong. (If you're right, the question could have been much clearer. Then again, the question could certainly have been clearer ;). )